# Call to undefined relationship in Eloquent, Laravel 5.7

Tags: postgresql, eloquent, laravel-5.7

I am four hours in this. I just cannot see the problem. I using Postgres not Mysql.

```
class ValorVariacao

   public $table = 'valores_variacoes';  

   protected function tipoVariacao()
  {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\TipoVariacao', 'tipo_atributo_id', 'id');
   }
```

The other class of the relationship.

```
 class TipoVariacao

  public $table = 'tipos_variacoes';  

 public function valorVariacao() {


    return $this->hasMany('App\ValorVariacao', 'id', 'tipo_atributo_id');


 }
```

The relevant structure of the table

```
   valores_variacoes               tipos_variacoes
     id                                 id
   tipo_atributo_id
```

Calling this I get undefined relationship:

```
   return ValorVariacao::with('tipoVariacao')->get();
```

error:

```
  Call to undefined relationship [tipoVariacao] on model [App\ValorVariacao].
```

Comment: Maybe the issue is your name spacing? did you import the model `ValorVariacao` into your controller? aka `use App\ValorVariacao;`

Comment: No, if I call the inverse of the relationship it works. TipoVariacao::with('valorVariacao')->get();

Comment: The `tipoVariacao()` method has to be public.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir, that's it! Can you post an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relationship method has to be public:

```php
public function tipoVariacao()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\TipoVariacao', 'tipo_atributo_id', 'id');
}
```